# Git for web development based on same core engine

Tags: git, content-management-system

I'm trying to get into Git for managing my myriads of scripts and projects. I'm currently reworking several of my web sites and they will be based off a CMS that's available via GitHub called [Kirby](http://getkirby.com/).

Now I'm a bit confused how to best approach this. I've cloned the [Kirby repository](https://github.com/bastianallgeier/kirbycms) and I want to make some specific core changes to it (delete the example content for one). But then I also want to change stuff around for each of my three web sites (add site specific content, change templates, CSS, etc.).

Do I best create a new repository for each site based off of my changed core clone? Or is it best to create a branch for each site? What happens when I want to follow along with Kirby updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different strategies you could follow, but to make following up with updates in the future as easy as possible I would probably create one clone of the base CMS which I would then clean up to suit my needs.

This allows you to pull in changes from future updates (hopefully their updates are properly separated so you can just skip the ones related to demo content and include the rest).

Then, for each website you would make another clone and add the license and content as you see fit. For these clones you can pull in the filtered updates from you "naked" central clone.

Comment: Hi Dirk, that's how I started doing it. I just wasn't sure if that's a "proper" way to do this or if I make things harder on myself then I need to. Also on the first test merge (as chance would have it, Kirby got updated last week) the examples popped up again. But that might just have been me being unfamiliar with how Git does it's merges. I'll guess I'll have to do a bit more experimenting. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the feasability of syncing the central clone depends a bit on how commits are done in the source repo. I have in the past for something similar set up scripts to clean up the content after each update (mostly because a db was involved). This could work here too.

Comment: Good idea. That could work. Also, is this what cherry picking commits is for?

Comment: Absolutely; rebase can also be used and if you are for instance using a service like GitHub, you can even use the web interface to selectively apply specific commits and ignore others.